# Unable to get gpu count from OS environment in AWS sagemaker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, deep-learning, amazon-sagemaker

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

print(os.environ[ 'JUPYTER_PATH'])


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() 
args , _ =parser.parse_known_args()

print(os.environ)
parser.add_argument('--training', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_CHANNEL_TRANING'])
parser.add_argument('--gpu-count', type=int, default=os.environ['SM_NUM_GPUS'])


epochs         = 10
lr             = 0.2
batch_size     = 250
gpu_count      = 1
traning_dir    = args.training
#validation_dir = 


train_images = np.load(os.path.join(training_dir, 'traning.npz')[enter image description here][1])['image']
train_labels = np.load(os.path.join(training_dir, 'traning.npz'))['label']
train_images = np.load(os.path.join(validation_dir, 'validation.npz'))['image']
train_images = np.load(os.path.join(validation_dir, 'validation.npz'))['label']


K.set_image_data_format('channels_last')


train_images = train_image.reshape(train_images.shape[0], 32, 32, 3)
test_images = test_image.reshape(train_images.shape[0], 32, 32, 3)
input_shape = (32, 32, 3)


train_images = train_images.astype('float32')
test_images = test_images.astype('float32')
train_images /= 255 
test_images /= 255

train_labels = tenserflow.keras.utils.to.categorical(train_labels, 43)
test_labels =  tenserflow.keras.utils.to.categorical(test_labels, 43)




"""
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--epochs', type=int, default=1)
parser.add_argument('--learning-rate', type=float, default=0.001)
parser.add_argument('--batch-sizes', type=int, default=32)

print(os.environ)

parser.add_argument('--gpu-count', type=int, default=os.environ['SM_NUM_GPUS'])
parser.add_argument('--model-dir', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_MODEL_DIR'])
parser.add_argument('--training', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_CHANNEL_TRANING'])
parser.add_argument('--validation', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_CHANNEL_VALIDATION'])


args, _ = parser.parser_known_args()

"""
```

here is my error.

---

```
-
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-f9bc0f149346> in <module>
      8 
      9     print(os.environ)
---> 10     parser.add_argument('--gpu-count', type=int, default=os.environ['SM_NUM_GPUS'])
     11     parser.add_argument('--training', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_CHANNEL_TRANING'])
     12 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/os.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    679         except KeyError:
    680             # raise KeyError with the original key value
--> 681             raise KeyError(key) from None
    682         return self.decodevalue(value)
    683 

    **KeyError: 'SM_NUM_GPUS'**
```

---

[can't find dictionary in the environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcoHo.png)

[key error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXAjc.png)
can somebody please help me here?

Comment: Can you share the dockerfile that you used to customize your container? Did you follow instructions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/prebuilt-containers-extend.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like code is not getting the value from environment.

you must be not running code with argument `--gpu-count` so code is checking into at OS level environment varibles.

```
SM_NUM_GPUS=1
```

you can set it inside the code and check the reference at : https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-containers#sm_num_gpus

```
import os

# using it in argparse
parser.add_argument('num_gpus', type=int, default=os.environ['SM_NUM_GPUS'])

# using it as variable
num_gpus = int(os.environ['SM_NUM_GPUS'])
```

Comment: Now i am getting this error : KeyError: 'SM_CHANNEL_TRANING'

Comment: Suppose that two input channels, ‘train’ and ‘test’, were used in the call to the PyTorch estimator’s fit method, the following will be set, following the format “SM_CHANNEL_[channel_name]”:

SM_CHANNEL_TRAIN: A string representing the path to the directory containing data in the ‘train’ channel
SM_CHANNEL_TEST: Same as above, but for the ‘test’ channel.